# No Reverse Match error related to get_tabs

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to run Project Mwana through RapidSMS, but have run into a No Reverse Match error coming from {% get_tabs as tabs}. Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.2.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['mwana.apps.broadcast',
 'mwana.apps.tlcprinters',
 'south',
 'django_nose',
 'djtables',
 'rapidsms',
 'rapidsms.contrib.handlers',
 'rapidsms.contrib.ajax',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'rapidsms.contrib.export',
 'rapidsms.contrib.httptester',
 'rapidsms.contrib.messagelog',
 'rapidsms.contrib.messaging',
 'rapidsms.contrib.scheduler',
 'mwana.apps.echo',
 'mwana.apps.contactsplus',
 'mwana.apps.registration',
 'mwana.apps.agents',
 'mwana.apps.broadcast',
 'mwana.apps.labresults',
 'mwana.apps.reminders',
 'mwana.apps.location_importer',
 'mwana.apps.reports',
 'mwana.apps.training',
 'mwana.apps.help',
 'mwana.apps.alerts',
 'mwana.apps.locations',
 'mwana.apps.patienttracing',
 'mwana.apps.hub_workflow',
 'mwana.apps.stringcleaning',
 'mwana.apps.translator',
 'rapidsms.contrib.default',
 'eav',
 'uni_form',
 'people',
 'mwana.apps.nutrition',
 'mwana.apps.reports.webreports']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'mwana.middleware.LoginRequired']


Template error:
In template /root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/templates/layout.html, error at line 49
   Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'rapidsms.contrib.messagelog.views.message_log' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
   39 :                     </h1>


   40 :                 </div>


   41 : 


   42 :                 {% block auth %}


   43 :                 <div id="auth">{% if user.is_authenticated %}


   44 :                     <a href="{% url rapidsms-logout %}">{% trans "Log out" %} {{ user.username }}</a>{% else %}


   45 :                     <a href="{% url rapidsms-login %}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>{% endif %}


   46 :                 </div>


   47 :                 {% endblock %}


   48 : 


   49 :                  {% get_tabs as tabs %} 


   50 : 


   51 :                 <ul id="tabs">{% for tab in tabs %}


   52 :                     <li class="app-{{ tab.name }}{% if tab.is_active %} active{% endif %}">


   53 :                         <a href="{{ tab.url }}"><span>{{ tab.caption }}</span></a>


   54 :                     </li>{% endfor %}


   55 :                 </ul>


   56 : 


   57 :                 {% block page_tabs %}


   58 :                 {% endblock %}


   59 :             </div>


Traceback:
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  95.                     response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jackie/mwana/mwana/middleware.py" in process_view
  34.         return login_required(view_func)(request, * view_args, ** view_kwargs)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  37.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jackie/mwana/mwana/apps/reports/views.py" in malawi_reports
  129.      }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  186.     return t.render(context_instance)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  173.             return self._render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  72.             result = node.render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  125.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  72.             result = node.render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  72.             result = node.render(context)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/templatetags/tabs_tags.py" in render
  58.             tab.is_active = tab.url == request.get_full_path()
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rapidsms/templatetags/tabs_tags.py" in url
  35.         return reverse(self._view)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  351.             *args, **kwargs)))
File "/root/.virtualenvs/mwana-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  297.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'rapidsms.contrib.messagelog.views.message_log' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I am pretty sure I found the offending reverse field in tabs_tags.py, I just cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: ai ts=4 sts=4 et sw=4


import types
import threading
from functools import wraps
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver, reverse, RegexURLPattern
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.template import Variable

register = template.Library()


class Tab(object):
    def __init__(self, view, caption=None):
        self._view = view        
        self._caption = caption

    def _auto_caption(self):
        func_name = self._view.split('.')[-1]       # my_view
        return func_name.replace("_", " ").title()  # My View

    @property
    def url(self):
        """
        Return the URL of this tab.

        Warning: If this tab's view function cannot be reversed, Django
        will silently ignore the exception, and return the value of the
        TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID setting.
        """
        return reverse(self._view)

    @property
    def caption(self):
        return self._caption or self._auto_caption()
```

Also, as a note, I am a total novice living in a small rural town in Malawi (Africa) whose only coding experience is from using Visual Basic in MS Excel. I'm just figuring this stuff out as I go along, so please explain any solutions like you were talking to a kid. And if there's any other information needed, please let me know.

Comment: there are many reasons for why this happens, to diagnose this,
can you please answer these questions,
have you gone through the django framework tutorials?
also have you gone through the RapidSMS library tutorials?